# Calculating thd in python

Tags: python, numpy, arduino, fft, sampling

I'm trying to calculate the total harmonic distortion values of ac voltage supplied. I am sampling voltage data using Arduino at over 8 KHz rate and storing those data into a text file. Then I'm trying to calculate thd using the following code snippet written in python:

```
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.fftpack
    from scipy.fftpack import fft
    from numpy import genfromtxt

    sampled_data = genfromtxt('/../file.txt',delimiter=',')
    abs_yf=np.abs(fft(sampled_data))

    #As far as I know, THD=sqrt(sum of square magnitude of
    #harmonics+noise)/Fundamental value (Is it correct?)So I'm
    #just summing up square of all frequency data obtained from FFT,
    #sqrt() them and dividing them with fundamental frequecy value.

    def thd(abs_data):
    sq_sum=0.0
    for r in range(len(abs_data)):
       sq_sum=sq_sum+(abs_data[r])**2
    sq_harmonics=sq_sum-(max(abs_data))**2.0
    thd=100*sq_harmonics**0.5/max(abs_data)
    return thd

    print "Total Harmonic Distortion(in percent):"
    print thd(abs_yf)
```

Problem is, The obtained Thd values vary within 5% to 25% in my case. (In reality it's not more than 5% actually). What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to find out thd?

Comment: Check indent of your code, please

Comment: THD is only the the sum of the Harmonics, not every bin in the fft unless your fundamental period is exactly equal to the data record length.    

    If your fundamental frequency period isn't an exact integer divisor of the sample length then you should use a Window function and a record length that contains many periods of the fundamental

Comment: Actually I'm trying to calculate THD+N. According to wiki, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_harmonic_distortion) it includes noises(frequecies other than harmonics) too.

Comment: you still need the Windowing or exact integer multiple periods or your "noise" is actually spectral smearing.  The ADC data can also be contaminated with "spurs" - non harmonic tones from the ADC, sensor hardware or extraneous tones like power line frequency.  You should really plot the fft magnitude data and eyeball it

Answer (score 5):

Though this is long quiet, for anyone encountering this post like me: There are a couple of problems with the OP method.

1) The magnitudes returned by FFT include a magnitude of the 0 frequency bin, so the assumption that max(abs_data) is the magnitude corresponding to the fundamental frequency is not correct if there is any DC bias in the signal. This is a problem in the line

> thd = 100*sq_harmonics**0.5 / max(abs_data)

The amplitude associated with the 0 frequency can just be ignored as a quick solution.

2) The second half of the abs_data should be thrown out, it is a "mirrored" reflection of the first. This is due to the nature of the Fourier transform.

Both these issues can be addressed by changing the input to the function, i.e by replacing

> print thd(abs_yf)

with

> print( thd(abs_yf[1:int(len(abs_yf)/2) ]) )

where we have changed the input to not include the first or the last N/2 elements.

The result is still not ideal because the window needs to be exactly an integer number of cycles as the previous answers noted above. Testing with a pure sine with offset and adjusting the window demonstrates that the method works fairly well but fails terribly if significant window errors.

```
t0=0
tf = 0.02  # integer number of cycles
dt = 1e-4
offset = 0.5
N = int((tf-t0)/dt)
time = np.linspace(0.0,tf,N )    #;

commandSigFreq = 100
Amplitude = 2

waveOfSin = Amplitude*np.sin(2.0*pi*commandSigFreq*time) + offset

abs_yf = np.abs(fft(waveOfSin))
#print("freq is" + str(scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(sampled_data, dt )  ))
#As far as I know, THD=sqrt(sum of square magnitude of
#harmonics+noise)/Fundamental value (Is it correct?)So I'm
#just summing up square of all frequency data obtained from FFT,
#sqrt() them and dividing them with fundamental frequency value.

def thd(abs_data):
    sq_sum=0.0
    for r in range( len(abs_data)):
       sq_sum = sq_sum + (abs_data[r])**2

    sq_harmonics = sq_sum -(max(abs_data))**2.0
    thd = 100*sq_harmonics**0.5 / max(abs_data)

    return thd

print("Total Harmonic Distortion(in percent):")
print(thd(abs_yf[1:int(len(abs_yf)/2) ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that you add additional distortion by the measurement process itself.

If you compare an Arduino ADC with a high class measurement device, the values of the Arduino will very likely much worse. At least you need a very stable and jitter-free clock.

Furthermore, the output of the data (I guess via UART) might interfere with the timing of the ADC measurement.

Comment: Thanks but I did the same analysis using same data in MATLAB too. In that case, it shows results around 2%  which is good I guess. You can find the code [here] (http://pastebin.com/T7ib0N27) Maybe this is not entirely Arduino's fault then. (I don't have much idea about microcontroller hardware so correct me if I'm wrong ).I need to work with python in this case. So what can I do then?

Comment: Ok, then my assumption was wrong that you were using additional hardware. Anyhow, do not take your results overly serious, but I do not know your application - it might be sufficient. But f5r5e5d has a very valid argument. You should investigate that!